# positioning divs over another, CSS

Tags: html, css

i have came across a problem, i am fairly new to CSS but how do i make one div go over the other? This is my code:

```
#left_box
 {
margin-top: 0px;
min-width: 10%;
max-width: 10%;
height: 800px;
background: #C90;
border: thin 5px #33CCFF;
position: absolute;
z-index:1;
left: 16px;
top: 1px;
float:none;
}

#bar_outside
{

margin-top:75px;
min-width:10px;
max-width:2000px;
height:55px;
background:#ff69b4;
border:#ff69b4: 5px;
position:static;
z-index:2;
```

}

[image: I want the pink box to go over the orange box]

thanks for your help!

Comment: change `position:static;` to `position:relative;` z-index can't apply static positioned element

Comment: For making `z-index` work, you must use `position:relative/absolute/fixed`.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6RLqz/ Like that?

Comment: Thanks AlienArrays thats exactly how i wanted it!

Answer (score 3):

If you want one div to be on top of the other, you can change the `position: static` in your `#bar_outside` to `position:relative` as the z-index property just works for relative, absolute or fixed. [See the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3eBe3/).

If you want the divs to be positioned one to the side of the other, use the `float` CSS attribute accordingly in both your CSS classes. [See the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xYEeS/).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need position: absolute. Float left and define width